# Can't apply CSS name dynamically with async pipe

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have a component like this:

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Job } from '../models';
import { PipelineJobsQuery, PipelineSelectQuery } from '../queries';
import { PipelineJobsService } from '../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'pi-pipeline-jobs',
  templateUrl: './pipeline-jobs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pipeline-jobs.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class PipelineJobsComponent implements OnInit {
  public pipelineName: string;
  public pipelineJobs$: Observable<Job[]>;

  constructor(
    private readonly pipelineJobsQuery: PipelineJobsQuery,
    private readonly pipelineJobsService: PipelineJobsService,
    private readonly pipelineSelectQuery: PipelineSelectQuery
  ) {}

  public getJobStatus(job: Job): string {
    const status: string = job.next_build
      ? job.next_build.status
      : job.finished_build
        ? job.finished_build.status
        : 'no-build-status';

    console.log(job, status);
    return status;
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    // Reload the pipelineJobs when the selectedPipeline changes
    this.pipelineSelectQuery.selectedPipeline$.subscribe(pipeline => {
      this.pipelineJobsService.getPipelineJobs(pipeline);
      this.pipelineJobs$ = this.pipelineJobsQuery.pipelineJobs;
      this.pipelineName = pipeline;
    });
  }
}
```

with the following template:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let job of (pipelineJobs$ | async)"
          class="job-card job-card-{{ getJobStatus(job) }}">
    {{job.name}} - <strong>{{getJobStatus(job)}}</strong>
</mat-card>
```

and stylesheet:

```
.job-card {
  margin: 8px;
}

.job-card-succeeded {
  background-color: green;
}
```

If I apply the class name like that, then the template doesn't render the `mat-card` elements as cards. I know that the data is there at the time the `getJobStatus()` function is called so I'm unsure why it breaks the CSS for the cards. This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

This is what it ends up looking like:

[image]

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: Can you try a static data and see how it renders please?

Comment: Also try it with default  changeDetection

Comment: I tried it with default changeDetection and it doesn't work. Lemme try with static data.

Comment: I tried with static data and it still doesn't work.

Comment: can you do a favor, post the code in https://stackblitz.com I will fix it for you quickly

Comment: Are you overriding material class? if so it's tricky. Move the class to your root style.css/scss and override the class and make sure to use !important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are binding to `class` you are overriding all classes applied to `mat-card` by the component itself - specifically `mat-card` which is why it no longer appears like a card. Don't bind to `class`, instead use `ngClass` which is intended for this  purpose - *adding* classes rather than *setting* classes:

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let job of (pipelineJobs$ | async)"
        [ngClass]="'job-card job-card-' + getJobStatus(job)">
    {{job.name}} - <strong>{{getJobStatus(job)}}</strong>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Avoid pure functions. User pipes instead. The component is rendered every change detection cycle and Angular Change Detection runs a lot.

Comment: Sure - but this was to correct the OP's original usage of `class` to `ngClass` - pure functions vs. pipes is off topic for this answer.